# How to use Doctrine Create query in form type class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

If I use this code then I can create new object without any problem:

```
 ->add('user', 'entity', array(
                 'class' => 'Acme\Entity\User',
                 'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options){
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');}
                ))
```

But if I set some parameter like this:

```
'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                            return $er->createQueryBuilder('u') 
->where('u.id = :id')
->setParameter('id',$options['id'])
->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');}
                ))
```

Then I can see the options correctly in select box , but when i submit the form , i get NULL values for User Object. Am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$options['id']` might be a string. Try this:

```
->setParameter('id',intval($options['id']))
```